# How we can extend the capabilities of Solr in our own Java application using the native API

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

I am new to Solr and looking to use it like a embedded Search engine in java based jetty based server. And to achieve it, we are looking for APIs (something like low level APIs or client SDK) to embed the search in our custom java application. Currently, we are using the Lucene APIs (version 4.4) for "full text search capabilities" but now the need to extend it to the next level by implementing sharding, replication, routing, caching etc. using APIs.

Could you direct me on it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for this one:
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj